# Where is the services file?

Tags: web-services, drupal-8

I can't find my services file inside sites/default. Where is it and how do i get at it? I know I'm supposed to replicate it. But its not there at all. I've search properly and the complaint is absent.

Answer (score 2):

Initially a **Drupal 8** has a `default.services.yml` file provided at `sites/default/default.services.yml`. If you want to override the default settings for the services you need to copy that file & rename it to `services.yml` and adjust only that file.

If for some reason both of those files are missing, re-download the archive for your 8.x installed version & copy the YAML file.